# Java compiler error: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, compiler-errors

While doing maven build, I am getting below error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project SimplyAuth: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Admin/Project/dev/workspaces/Java/Auth/src/test/java/com/data/sAuth/JwtClaimsBuilderTest.java:[13,36] method generateToken in class com.comdata.sAuth.util.JwtClaimsBuilder cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: com.comdata.simplyAuth.model.ICDUserDetails
[ERROR] found: no arguments
[ERROR] reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

This is the method in controller class:

```
@Autowired
private JwtClaimsBuilder jwtBuilder;
@RequestMapping("/GetUser")
public String getToken(@RequestBody ICDUserDetails details) {
    return jwtBuilder.generateToken(details);
}

public String generateToken(ICDUserDetails userDetails) {
    JwtClaims claims = new JwtClaims();
    claims.setStringClaim("username", userDetails.getUserName());
    claims.setStringClaim("userCulture", userDetails.getUserCulture());
}


public class ICDUserDetails {
    private String UserName;
    private String UserCulture;
    private List<ICDAccount> AccountCodes;

    public ICDUserDetails() {

    }

    public ICDUserDetails(String userName, String userCulture, List<ICDAccount> accountCodes) {
        this.UserName = userName;
        this.UserCulture = userCulture;
        this.AccountCodes = accountCodes;
    }
    //getters, setters
}
```

Why model class is not an valid type to be used here?

FIX:
Its just a glitch in workspace, restart IDE works for me.

Comment: It sounds like you just called a method without parameters that requires one.

Comment: Can you tell whats wrong in the above code, parameters are provided in the method

Comment: Share your `JwtClaimsBuilderTest` class as well

Comment: @Dileep76 the problem is in class `src/test/java/com/data/sAuth/JwtClaimsBuilderTest.java`